# Пишу бот с openai в телеграмм когда пишу import telebot появляется ошибка

Tags: python, telebot

Выдаёт

> ```
> file, line 2 in module import telebot
> ```

вот код:

````
import telebot
import openai
from config import TgKey
from config import OpenAiKey

openai.api_key = OpenAiKey
bot = telebot.Telebot(TgKey)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')```
````

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю config это твой второй файл.

```
import telebot
import openai

openai.api_key = "123"
bot = telebot.TeleBot("123")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')
```

вот твой же код где я просто исправил Telebot На TeleBot и код запустился. Будь внимательнее!